# How can i add a UIView under my tab bar controller programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, tabbar, adview

I am trying to see how i can add a UIView under my UITabBarController so i can add ads to my app, I cant seem to figure out any way to constrain my UIView to the bottom of the tab bar. Is this possible?

**EDIT:** By bottom of the tab bar i mean below the tab bar

Comment: What do you mean by *"under my UITabBarController"*? Do you mean the actual TabBar? and by "Under" do you mean Under as in behind (partially covered)? Or as in below? Show an image of what you *want* to achieve.

Comment: Sorry i mean below the tab bar, so essentially i would move the tab bar up and display a ad below it

Comment: If on iOS 10 and below: `self.viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout 
 |= UIRectEdgeBottom`.. If on iOS 11+: `[view.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor];` instead of `[view.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.safeLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor]` Notice the difference on iOS 11.. One is safeLayoutGuide.bottom (this one will be ABOVE the tabBar) and the other is view.bottom (this one will be UNDER the tabBar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create a UIView in my UITabBarController

```
lazy var bannerAd: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .black
    return view
}()
```

And then pin it to the bottom like so:

```
  view.addSubview(bannerAd)

    bannerAd.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
    bannerAd.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    bannerAd.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

then to move up the Tab Bar i did so like this:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        if !didStyleTabBar {
            self.tabBar.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
            var tabFrame = self.tabBar.frame

            tabFrame.size.height = tabBarHeight
            tabFrame.origin.y = tabFrame.origin.y - 44
            self.tabBar.frame = tabFrame

            didStyleTabBar = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: This add a view under the tab bar but this view will not responds to any events. Suppose you should add a button in it, it will not responds.

Answer (score 15):

Try this add see:

[image]

Follow these steps to achieve it:

1. Add `UIViewController` in root of your storyboard
2. Add `Container View` inside `UIViewController`
3. Add `AdView` below `Container view`
4. Embed `UITabbarController` with `Container view`

Comment: @RickS - I was typing up the same answer when Kunal posted. There is no reason why you ***cannot*** do this programmatically.